# Printing large HTML data times out

Tags: java, servlets, timeout, flush

I'm printing a long HTML page in a simple way:

```java
try {
    PrintWriter out = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
    out.println("LARGE DATA...");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the page times out in browser everytime. I know i can fix it by powering up the server but is there some way more optimize in codes? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Try using `httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()` instead.

Comment: Where is your "large data" coming from? Do you have it in memory at the point you're trying to write it to the response? If not, the problem might be that it's actually the reading of the data that causes the slowness...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen the data is about 10,000 database rows which are parsed and convert to HTML elements...

Comment: Yeah, so I reiterate my point: it's reading the 10000 database rows and potentially the parsing and conversion that's causing the slowness.